# Lighting neutral

Tags: switch, light-fixture, neutral, wifi

Can anyone explain about lighting neutral wires (blue)?

I have a 3year old house, which has blue wires in the back boxes.  I am assuming that this is the neutral.  On my current 1 gang 2 way switch there is L1, L2 Common & earth.

If I were to fit a wifi light switch requiring a neutral connection, am I safe to connect these up as indicated, and please, can anyone explain in layman's terms how this works?

Comment: We need to know where in the world you are. In the UK and Europe [blue is indeed neutral](https://p3connectors.com/2018/04/30/electrical-wiring-colours-standards/) but, in the US and Australia, Blue can be an additional hot

Comment: OP is in the Britverse or EU influenced world.  **2-way means SPDT i.e. US 3-way.**  L1 and L2 are what we call travelers.

Comment: Never match color to color, *especially not in 2[3]-way circuits, double especially not in 2[3]way circuits*, unless you fully understand the *functions* of each wire, and have colored electrical tape to mark them by function.  Did I mention this is doubly so in 2[3]way circuits?

Comment: In the UK gents.